# how to display My table data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have collaborators table in My Laravel app see this following
[image]

I need collaborator_id print in My index.blade.php file who equel with Auth::user()->id to logged with the system. I wrote following code in My Collaboration Model

```
public function scopeColabo($query){
 return $query->where('collaborator_id',Auth::user()->id);}
```

and this is My ProjectCollaboratorController function

```
public function index(){
$collaborators = Collaboration::colabo()->getreturn view('collaborators.index')->withCollaboration($collaborators);}
```

and this is My index.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
@if($collaboration)
<div class="row">
         @foreach ($collaboration as $proj)
           <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:5px;">
           <h2><a href="/projects/{{ $proj->id }}">{!! $proj->project_id !!}</a></h2>

           <p>Tasks: 0</p>
           <p>Comments: 0</p>
           <p>Attachments: 0</p>
           </div>

        @endforeach
     </div>
  @endif



   @if($collaboration->isEmpty())
     <h3>There are currently no Collaboration</h3>
@endif 
</div>
```

But when I click collaboration link index.blade.php file generate

```
There are currently no Projects
```

but in My table there is data....how can print collaborator_id in collaboration Table relete with current logged user?

Comment: Please avoid posting large screenshots with almost no information in them.

Comment: What is the current value of `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: logged user id is the current value of user

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **->with()** instead of **->withCollaboration**:

```
public function index() {
    $collaborators = Collaboration::colabo()->get();
    return view('collaborators.index')->with(compact('collaborators'));
}
```

or just pass your data as second parameter:

```
public function index() {
    $collaborators = Collaboration::colabo()->get();
    return view('collaborators.index', compact('collaborators'));
}
```

Comment: use your first code but occred following error "syntax error, unexpected 'with' (T_STRING)"

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the `collaborator_id` in the table which is used to log to test the system:

In the tests, in the logging account, data should match with collaborator data, so `collaborator_id` should match with the logged user id.

Comment: Hi Fernando - it's good that you solved your own problem. But for the benefit of other site users, could you give a full explanation of what your fix was (with code/table samples where relevant), and then Accept your own answer?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I did not do new code. code is same but when I test I had does some mistake that means in My logging account data didn't match with collaborator data (have not match collaborator_id with logged user id)

Comment: OK, that sounds useful - you could improve your answer by editing it, and adding in that extra explanation.